# git through SOCKS proxy won't respond after a while

Tags: git, proxy, socks

I'm using a SOCKS proxy to push changes to a repo only allowed from a specific IP, the command I use is `'ssh -D port -f -C -q -N user@xxx.xxx.xx.xx'` and everything works ok, but after some time when I try to pull or push this is the error that returns: `Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack.` However I use this same proxy for Firefox and it never stops working.

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: You may have a firewall dropping the connection if it is idle too long.  Consider enabling keep alives:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34004/4869

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to connect to the enterprise version of Github. And I would recommend debugging this connection. Please use a command similar to
`ssh -D port -v -N user@xxx.xxx.xx.xx`. When you try to connect you'll get debug message in console. For example:

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Operation timed out
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9100 for xx.xx.xx.xx port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 44848 to 127.0.0.1 port 9100, nchannels 3
```

The first message is for error `Failed to receive SOCKS5 connect request ack.`. The second one is for a successful connection.